# How to prevent two users editing the same list in Sharepoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, editing

I have created a list for booking appointments in Sharepoint that multiple users have access to. I know that if two users edit the same item on my list the second person to click save will receive an error message and not be able to save.

My question is: Is there a way to lock the item if it is already open on a different computer? This would save users having to enter lots of information only to have to re-do it if they are double booking the appointment.

Thank you!

Cher

Comment: This can be of a helpful : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9ca7f5b2-6003-4202-a5df-cc96b3d5dc63/restricitng-multiple-users-to-edit-the-same-list-item-at-same-time-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you have a field that, when is filled, you know that the item is not available anymore.

Make a jquery that will run every minute(or 30 seconds) that will check this field for this item. If the field is filled, alert ("Sorry, The item is now occupied") and get him to another page(?) or something else.

In that way you don't lock it but the user knows when is unavailable.

Locking is another thing and poses a lot of questions: If someone opens the items and goes for a coffee, will it be  locked for 30 mins? if it leaves office? If it opens 10 items to reserve them and then fill the data ? There are workarounds but it won't be an easy task: The main problem would be the cancel button and orphaned locked items.If you have strict requirements, I could show a way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OTTB functionality in SharePoint. You need to do Custom code or JQuery/**JSLink**

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use Content Approval setting for that list. Go to List Settings -> Versioning Settings.

Select Yes for Require content approval.
You can select No for versioning (optional)
Set Draft Item security to "only user who can approve items".